# How to get the project directory from a Visual Studio Add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I want to get the project directroy from an Add-In. But if I use the following code:

```
string projectDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

it returns `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE\\`

How can I get the Project Directory of the project that uses the Add-In?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem:

```
string projectDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Answer (score 3):

See here for a list of Visual Studio variables you can use

[VS Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx)

```
$(ProjectDir)
```

gives the project directory

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I use it in my code? If I use it like this: `string projectDir = "$(ProjectDir)"` it is just parsing it like "$(ProjectDir)".

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use
`Environment.CurrentDirectory`